# How to use python change a string into list cut by ','?

Tags: python

I have a string like this

```
string_ = 'hello world, world, hello, stackoverflow, me, not, me'
```

How to change it into a list like this?

```
['hello world', 'world', 'hello', 'stackoverflow', 'me', 'not', 'me']
```

I have try

```
alist = list(string_)
```

but when I format `alist`
It shows

```
['h', 'e', 'l', ... ]
```

Comment: [`string_.split(', ')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
alist = string_.split(', ')
```